# File not created in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use below PowerShell script to create a hash file for autopilot enrollment purpose. While the folder Auto is created but the `hw.csv` file cannot be created. Need advice how to modify it.

```
md $PSScriptRoot\Auto

Set-Location $PSScriptRoot\Auto

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

Install-Script -Name Get-WindowsAutopilotInfo -Force

Get-WindowsAutopilotInfo.ps1 -OutputFile $PSScriptRoot\Auto\hw.csv
```

Comment: What's happening when you run it? Are you getting any errors, in which case what are they?

Comment: Can you provide more information by running it within PowerShell ISE? What line is the last line that successfully runs?

Comment: Setting execution policy during script is not going to help for that session and also requires administrative privileges. I bet this is where your script is failing. Instead, consider running powershell with the -executionpolicy unrestricted parameters to run your script once as unrestricted.

Comment: While aliases are very convenient in using PS for day to day tasks in the terminal window, I recommend not using these when writing scripts, because aliases DO change and they are not as readable as the cmdlets they represent.